# Como retirar essa linha do TabLayout?

Tags: java, android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém aqui sabe como o tiro essa linha verde?

Obrigado desde já ^^

Answer (score 0):

O `TabLayout` possui alguns atributos que ajudam a estilizar o `tabIndicator`.

Mas acredito que apenas deixar a altura do `tabIndicator` igual a zero resolve o seu problema:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
```

Acho que vale a pena dar uma olhada na documentação do [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

Comment: Valei!! :D Sabe como eu altero o tamanho de um icon na tabLayout?

Comment: Eu coloquei para  buscar a imagem na pasta drawable e colocar nas tabs. Só que o icon fica pequeno. Como alterá-los?